# What am I getting wrong here

Tags: go, hash, bcrypt

```
func SignInValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {
payload := sl.Current().Interface().(SignInPayload)

user := services.FindUserByEmail(payload.Email)

if user.ID == 0 {
    sl.ReportError(payload.Email, "Email", "email", "email", "Unregistered user!")
}

fmt.Println(user.Password, payload.Password)

err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(payload.Password))
fmt.Println(err)

if err != nil {
    sl.ReportError(payload.Password, "Password", "password", "password", "Password is incorrect!")
}
}
```

Above is my code to sign in user. I encrypt user's password and save to db. Then to user login, compare hashed password and plain password. And I am getting an error `crypto/bcrypt: hashedPassword is not the hash of the given password`. Whats wrong?

Update: This is my sign-up endpoint and logic to hash pasword:

```
func SignUpMain(ctx iris.Context) orm.Users {
activationToken := uuid.NewString()

payload := orm.Users{
    ActivationToken:          activationToken,
    ActivationState:          constants.UserActivationState["PENDING"],
    ActivationTokenExpiresAt: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 7),
    LastLoginAt:              time.Now(),
    LastLoginFromIpAddress:   ctx.RemoteAddr(),
}

if err := ctx.ReadJSON(&payload); err != nil {
    ctx.StopExecution()
    panic("Error to read JSON")
}

hash := hashedPassword(payload.Password)
payload.Password = string(hash)

user := services.SignUp(payload)
services.GenerateToken(user, ctx)

// Notification
libs.SlackNewUser(user)
mailer.SendActivationAccountMail(user, activationToken)

return user
}


func hashedPassword(password string) []byte {
hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 10)

if err != nil {
    panic("Error to encrypt password")
}

return hash
```

}

Comment: Show the code that hashes & saves the password as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when I omit the password from the model.

```
Password     string   `gorm:"column:password;type:varchar(255)" json:"-"`
```

So `payload.Password` is always an empty string. I just added it to the json tag. And, the problem has been solved.

```
Password     string   `gorm:"column:password;type:varchar(255)" json:"password"`
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check whether the data are sent correctly.Just print the payload and check the values are mapping correctly. Next, you need to check whether checking is done correctly

```
bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(password))
           Must be the already hashed PW ^              ^ Plain Text Password to compare
```